# Array item call

Tags: php, arrays

I have problem with calling Array which are form redux framework to wordpress

when i execute this:

```
print_r ($ka_opt['theme-order']);
```

i have this result:

```
Array ( [nr2] => 1 [nr3] => 1 [nr1] => 1 )
```

I need to call specific item from this array for example first item, i tryed this to call first possition but dont work:

```
echo $ka_opt['theme-order'][0];
```

whats wrong? i dont know how to call variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), not a numerically keyed array. You can't use numerical keys with associative arrays. You *must* use their proper keys:

```
echo $ka_opt['theme-order']['nr2'];
```

If you want the first item you can us [`array_shift()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php):

```
echo array_shift($ka_opt['theme-order']);
```

If you want a deeper array element you can use `array_slice()`:

```
// get second element, assuming PHP5.4+
echo array_slice(array_values($ka_opt['theme-order']), 1, 1)[0];
```

And, of course, you can always loop through it to get the values you seek.